# Is the Sinc function continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, continuity

Is  $\frac{\sin x}{x}$ a continuous function or is it not?

I am confused with the fact that at zero it cannot be defined yet the limit surely exists.

So, the question of its continuity arises.

Comment: An (arguably) elegant way to avoid any discontinuity problems is to define $\mathrm{sinc}$ as the Fourier transform of the box function. Since that is compactly supported, its transform is continuous everywhere.

Answer (score 12):

Notice that the complete definition of $\operatorname{sinc}$ on $\mathbb R$ is
$$ \operatorname{sinc}(x) = \begin{cases} \frac{\sin x}{x} & x\ne 0, \\ 1, & x = 0, \end{cases} $$
which is continuous.
There is exactly one continuous function on $\mathbb R$, which agrees with $x\mapsto \sin(x) / x$ on $\mathbb R\setminus\{0\}$, namely $\operatorname{sinc}$.
Thus, people are used to lazily write $\operatorname{sinc}(x) = \sin(x) / x$ only.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on that please. Also, as it stands is the function continuous?

Comment: What about the raw sinx/x function which is defined just as that with no special value given at x = 0 ?

Comment: @SilverSlash the raw $\sin x/x$ function isn't $\operatorname{sinc}$.

Comment: As @luka5z wrote, the maximal domain of $x\mapsto \sin(x) / x$ is $\mathbb R\setminus\{ 0 \}$ and it is continuous there.

Comment: @Ruslan Okay I agree, but still why don't you entertain me for the heck of it. 
Is the NOT sinc function: sinx/x continuous?

Comment: Yes! It is. "The quotient of two continuous functions is a continuous function wherever the denominator is non-zero."

Comment: @SilverSlash Just as trivial, there are fields in which $\operatorname{sinc}(x)$ is $\sin(\pi x) / (\pi x)$.

Comment: @luka5z Would this language be correct then, in describing SilverSlash's question in the comments?  $f:\mathbb R\setminus\{0\}\to\mathbb R$ where $f(x) =\sin x / x$ is a continuous function on its domain, yet has a removable *singularity* at $x=0$. I'm unsure if my language is correct, but I think Silver wants to address the fact that this function is indeed singular at a point (yet he or she has been using the word discontinuous in its stead).

Comment: Aside: depending on your setting, the *complete* definition might also have $\mathop{\mathrm{sinc}}(+\infty) = \mathop{\mathrm{sinc}}(-\infty) = 0$ or $\mathop{\mathrm{sinc}}(\infty) = 0$.